# How to insert a portion of HTML file via PHP?

Tags: php, html, include

I don't want to open multiple php files,
I want to include several HTML files in one HTML document, then call every section of HTML by an ID or sth via include() in PHP on other pages.

Yes I know I can request it via $_POST but if there is any other easy way please suggest.

eg;

<div... </div --> For banner
<di v    id="slideshow" ... <div --> For slideshow ...

```html
//This is one part of a div tag

<div class="div-proj">
    <a href="">
        <h2>Projelerimiz</h2>
    </a>
    <div>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/boya1.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/fayans2.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/laminat2.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/urun6.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/tuvalet.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/ofis-deco.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/mutfak banyo tadilat.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
        <a href="" class="a-proj"><img src="images/JPEG/isi3.jpg" alt="" class="img-proj">
            <!-- <h4>ABCD</h4> -->
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

//This is another part of html that I want to embed in my index.php file
//But these div tags are so so small that I don't want to create another
//html file for each one of them

    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg');">
            <h3>Explore the world</h3>
            
        </div>
            <div class="panel " style="background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpjQWjchSCI_21ZBKw4XPFSUjWmEGA1_29AQ&usqp=CAU');">
            <h3>Wild Forest</h3>
            
        </div>
            <div class="panel " style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/abstract-wavy-object-picture-id1198271727?b=1&k=20&m=1198271727&s=170667a&w=0&h=b626WM5c-lq9g_yGyD0vgufb4LQRX9UgYNWPaNUVses=');">
            <h3>Sunny Beach</h3>
            
        </div>
        <div class="panel four" style="background-image: url('https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/thumb-1920-82317.jpg')">
            <h3>City on winter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel five " style="background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrLv6jLJFNc_zpxhDTh6lR6SJdELHGvjW-9WV_JTm2hdGxmpNlYLg6rFXBSUDDt6znQ-4&usqp=CAU');">
            <h3>Mountains - Clouds</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

//I want to have multiple small div tags like this
```

I want to have multiple sections like this but call them via PHP.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried (code). What does not work as expected and what debugging have you done? Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please revisit my code

Comment: Following the MVC application design pattern you should create as many HTML files as parts (in your case divs) you need. In large php development it is recommended to separate Views (presentation), Model (application data and business logic) and Controllers. Look for [MVC tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+php+tutorial) to learn more about it. If you still persist in your own style of coding then you can set vars inside your php code with html content and use them instead the include/require html, like `$div_container='<html code>';` escaping the `'` char if found in your html code

Comment: `I don't want to create another html file for each one of them`. Ok, so don't. If you want the content to be re-usable then you could simply put them into a function, or store the content in a database. Or you could do a more fundamental redesign of your application structure, as masterguru suggests. Or consider whether you can use a CMS. Or, or or...there are so many options, the question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow.